# CSS Div hidden not working well in laravel 5

Tags: html, css, laravel

I am using Css to hide the comment with div hidden,if user clicked load more the comment will showing. But if there was multiple status. All comment will load togather when button clicked. What is the problem here?

```
<style>

/*Comment pagination*/
#comment {
display:none;
}
</style>
```

This is my view

```
 @if($post->comments()->count()===0)
                            @else
<div class="inner-all block">
   <a href="#" id="loadMore-{{$post->id}}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" style="margin-top:3px; ">Load More Comment ({{ $post->comments()->count() }})</a>
</div>
@endif
```

And this is my Comment Div

```
@foreach($post->comments as $comment)
                                <div id="comment">
                            <div class="line no-margin"></div><!-- /.line -->

                            <div class="media inner-all no-margin">
                                <div class="pull-left">
                                    <img src="{{ asset('user_profile_image/'. $comment->user->profile_image) }}" alt="{{$comment->user->name}}" class="img-post2">
                                </div><!-- /.pull-left -->
                                <div class="media-body">
                                    <a href="{{ route('profile.index',['id'=>$comment->user->id]) }}" class="h4"><span style="font-size: medium;">{{$comment->user->name}}</span></a>
                                    <medium class="block text-muted">{{ $comment->comment }}</medium><br>
                                    <em class="text-xs text-muted">Posted on <span class="text-danger">{{$comment->created_at->diffForHumans()}}</span></em>
                                </div><!-- /.media-body -->
                            </div><!-- /.media -->
                                </div>
                                @endforeach
```

Then i using javascript to detect the action.

```
 @foreach($posts as $post)
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#comment").slice(0, 4).show();
        $("#loadMore-{{$post->id}}").on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("div:hidden").slice(0, 18).slideDown();
            if ($("div:hidden").length == 0) {
                $("#load").fadeOut('slow');
            }
            /**
            $('html,body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
            }, 1500);
             **/
        });
    });

</script>
@endforeach
```

I expect using different id to track which div should be active, but seem like does not working. Any suggestion here?

Comment: as far as I understood the line `<div id="comment">` can repeat in result html?

Comment: `$("#comment").slice(0, 4)` isn't correct, because "#comment" - is an `id` (unique) selector, so it will filter out only first instance and ignore all the rest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you can try to use `this` to get different div

```
 $("div:hidden")
```

to

```
$(this)
```

and  `id="comment"` is unique, change to `class="comment"` is better in foreach !

Answer (score 0):

You give all your divs containing comments the id `id="comment"`. Then in your JavaScript, you select every element with the id `"#comment"`, which is all of your comments. Best solution is to give your comments a different ID.